# Subfigs captions beside images

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I have this LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cat.pdf}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cat.pdf}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cat.pdf}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{3 subfigures: (a), (b) and (c).}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like the `caption`s of the `subfigure`s (in this case only the letter) to appear to the left of the images, and not below. This is an image of the desired output:

[image: desired output]

I find it really frustrating that such a simple thing can't be done in a simple way (I still can't find how to do it).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Put sub-images in table. One column use for sub-captions, another for images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tabular` as suggested by Zarko. This is another method where we use two `subfigure`s, in one we place only sub caption and in second, only figure. Don't forget to leave a blank line in the middle as I did.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.05\linewidth}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.05\linewidth}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.05\linewidth}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{3 subfigures: (a), (b) and (c).}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust `0.05\linewidth` in `\begin{subfigure}{0.05\linewidth}` if you have text as caption so that it doesn't look narrow.

Answer (score 1):

With the `floatrow` package, this is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \floatsetup[subfigure]{style=plain,capposition = beside, capbesideposition={left, center},capbesidesep=none, capbesidewidth =0.5em, rowpostcode = captionskip}
  \ffigbox{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}[1]
      \fcapside{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{dejeuner.jpeg}}
    \end{subfloatrow}\\
    \begin{subfloatrow}[1]
      \fcapside{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{dejeuner.jpeg}}
      {\caption{}}
    \end{subfloatrow}\\
    \begin{subfloatrow}[1]
      \fcapside{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{dejeuner.jpeg}}
      { \caption{}}
    \end{subfloatrow}\\
    }{\caption{3 subfigures: (a), (b) and (c).}
    \label{fig:label}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]